# How to set a DataList.SelectedItem equal to a uniqeItemId

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of objects called dashboard which holds a list of Announcements with their AnnouncementId. My DataListAnnouncements.DataSource is equal to the dashboard but I can't figure out how to get the selectedItem equal to the item that I am selecting in the client side.

What Currently is happening is when I select an unread announcement, it displays the message with some css, but it does that to the wrong announcement at the moment.

```
protected void DataListAnnouncements_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        IList<DashBoardView> dashboard = new List<DashBoardView>();
        dashboard = (IList<DataObjects.DashBoardView>)ListOfObjects;
        UnreadAnnouncement unread = UnreadAnnouncements;
        if (e.CommandArgument != null)
        {
            if (unread != null)
            {
                unread.WasRead = true;
                UpdateUnreadAnnouncement(unread);
                att = unread.AnnouncementId;
            }
        }


        dashboard[e.Item.ItemIndex].WasRead = unread.WasRead;


        DataListAnnouncements.DataSource = Session["dashboard"];
        DataListAnnouncements.SelectedItem = dashboard[e.Item.ItemIndex]
        (DataListAnnouncements.SelectedItem = att <---- Something Like this is what I would like to implement?)
        Session["dashboard"] = dashboard;
        bindDataList();
        }
        }
```

as you see now, I have it using the dashboard[e.Item.ItemIndex].WasRead = unread.WasRead line, but this proves to not work since the index is not always what I want. So I want to use an attribute. I looked around a bit but I am still fuzzy on how to implement it on the C# and asp side. 
and this is my ASP.

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <table width="880px">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCol">
                            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' CssClass="bold" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UnreadAnnouncementId") %>' ID="titleLabel" /></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="created">
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Effective", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' CssClass="created" runat="server" ID="Label4" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' runat="server" ID="Label2" />
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' runat="server" ID="Label3" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="one-long-line">
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("details") %>' CssClass="details" runat="server" ID="detailsLabel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <table width="880px" cellpadding="10px">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCol">
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' CssClass="bold" runat="server" ID="titleLabel" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="wasRead" Text='<%# Eval("wasRead") %>' Visible="false" Enabled="false" />

                            <td class="created">
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Effective", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' CssClass="created" runat="server" ID="Label4" />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' runat="server" ID="Label2" />
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' runat="server" ID="Label3" />
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="deailsTD" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("details") %>' CssClass="details" runat="server" ID="detailsLabel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
```

I want to be able to click on a item in the datagrid, and it will expand that item and show me the details.

Comment: Did you look at the value of "e.Item.ItemIndex"?Is this right? And is the new "dashboard" has the same value as the displayed "dashboard" ?

Comment: e.Item.ItemIndex returns the int of the Item before the Datalist gets updated. So if i click on object indexed at [2] in the list it actually gets [3] in dashboard. And I tried doing a if(itemIndex != 0) itemIndex-- but the selectedItem binding in the xaml still shows the css in the wrong place. It shows it it in the [3] still and not the [2].

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SelectedIndex', not SelectedItem'. Source: [How to: Allow Users to Select Items in DataList Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75670ez0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
 It could be like this:

```
DataListAnnouncements.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
```

From your code it is not clear what is the relation between `dashboard` and `att`. If there's any way to find the `att` in dashboard and find it's position, you can do like this:

```
DataListAnnouncements.SelectedIndex = attposition;
```

**EDIT :** There's an easy way to control background color of `DataList`s Items. We can parse each item in `DataList`'s ItemBound and set BackColor like below:

```
protected void DataListAnnouncements_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem||
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem
        )
    {
        // Here BackColor - Grey: WasRead; Yellow: Unread
        var wasRead = ((DashBoardView)e.Item.DataItem).WasRead;
        e.Item.BackColor = wasRead? System.Drawing.Color.Gray: System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

    }

}
```

You can even expand it more by splitting the `if` condition into two:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){}
```

and

```
if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem){}
```

Comment: att is just an int holding the the unreadAnnouncementId which I would liek that to reference by DataListAnnouncements.(selectedSomething). I tried using selectedIndex and I could not get it to work with many various ways so I would like to use another way then selectedIndex. Thanks for feedback though.

Comment: I wonder if you have called `bindDataList()` in page load and forgot to wrap it in `if(!IsPostBack){}`.This is a common issue of non-working SelectedIndex.

Comment: bindDataList() wasn't in the if condition so I put it in there and my indexes are still off.

Comment: What happens when you add 1 to index like : `DataListAnnouncements.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex + 1;`?

Comment: I would have to subtract one with the way it is acting, and when I do that. I get closer to it working but it still doesn't work fully. The page is set up like a "facebook wall" where you have your announcements shortened, and when you click on the title, it expands the full view, AND has a blue highlight in the background. With your suggestion, it will expand the correct item, but, the highlight will still be on an incorrect announcement.

Comment: How do you highlight? There should be some way to highlight correct item. Are you using `SelectedItemStyle`?

Comment: I should have been more specific and said the color of the selectedItem needs to change to a different color, rather than it Highlighting. An example of what I mean is in outlook, when you have an unread message the color is different from the rest of them. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want different backcolor for unread message. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for being persistent on helping me, I really appreciate it. Currently I am not able to test the edit, but on Monday I can and I will leave another comment listing the results, and hopefully, marking this as answered.

Comment: Unfortunately that edit did the same thing as what was already working. When I click on the first item, it works, and any after that it doesn't.

Comment: I think there is an issue with saving the `dashboad[].WasRead`. You are saving it in `Session` and probably `ListOfObjects` never gets it from `Session`. So, WasRead is false. In my test I have the `ListOfObjects` property to get from 'Container` for the first load and use it from session next times. So it is working in my test.

Comment: We decided to just remove the .OrderBy, that was what was giving us the problem so removing it let us use the indexes and everything just fine.